# How can I detect a method call in Java?

Tags: java, static-analysis

Not sure if this should be in StackOverflow or a different StackExchange site, so please forgive me if I’ve put it in the wrong place!

I’m currently working on a system which runs code that is sent to it. Is there any way I can use a static analysis tool to find out if, say, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is called? I know that PMD and things exist, but I can’t figure out how to use them for this example.

I know that I could use Java security managers, but that’s not what I’m after, as I’m literally just getting code, putting it in a file, running javac on it and then running it.

I also know I could do a regex sort of thing for that exact string, but `Runtime.getRuntime()` might be stored in a different variable.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple static analysis alone would not protect you: a way to trick the analysis would be to use the Reflection API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to get all current Threads and check the stacktrace. You kind of have to create a observer thread which constantly checks the method calls, though...

```
public static void foo(){ 
        Thread.currentThread();
        Map<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> allLiveThreads = Thread.getAllStackTraces(); 
        Set<Entry<Thread,StackTraceElement[]>>  entries = allLiveThreads.entrySet();

        for(Entry<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> entry : entries){

            System.out.print("Thread: '"+ entry.getKey().getName()+"'");

            if(entry.getValue().length>1) {
                String nameofMethod = entry.getValue()[1].getMethodName(); 
                System.out.println(" and method name '"+ nameofMethod+"()'");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(" with no methods.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way can be to write a wrapper for Runtime class and override all the exec functions, you can log and call the super function or drop the call.

In the source code you can replace the import of Java Runtime with your wrapper class before executing it.